# DRUPAL : Limit Views URL access

Tags: drupal, view

I've a view with an URL: "**/a**" so that if I visit [www.example.com/a](http://www.example.com/a) the view is showed. 
The problem is that the view shows even on all "**/a/something**" or "**/a/something/apple**" addresses so that no 404 error shows up.

Is the a way to limit view to its URL so that URL like: "**/a/something**" results in 404 error?

Thank you all!

Comment: Do you have arguments or contextual filters in this view?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I fixed it adding a Global:Null contextual filter!